# Arch, what is this bash error and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: arch-linux, locale

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF->8\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8)
[snorlax@arch ~]$
```

The locale is set up and properly configued, and I know this was something I did, but I don't remember where.  I'm using the current version (I think) of Arch.

## ~/.bashrc

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

## ~/.bash_profile

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: are you editing Unix configuration files in Windows and/or copying and pasting configurations from web pages?

Comment: No, there was no dual-boot with Windows, I was using only Arch-related stuff.  This is a completely Arch box - it was installed from an Arch ISO.

EDIT: I'm editing stuff here in Arch.  No Windows, and only using web pages as reference.

Comment: I suspect it might have to do with copy & posting from web pages. The system is not considering it two lines, I think. Delete the end of line before LANG, and create it again by hand.

Comment: Or use `dos2unix` on the file.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Could be, if it has a DOS CR.

Comment: Psst!  You're both over-thinking this.  What the Bourne Again shell prints is the uninterpreted value of the variable, here.  Stop seeing escape sequences and start seeing the characters `\ ` and `n`.  (-:

Comment: JdeBP what do you suggest I do then?

Comment: Have a look in your shell startup files (probably `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`) and see how you set the `LC_ALL` variable.

Comment: I’ll be sure to post or edit this comment with an output or outputs in a bit. On my way to university right now.

Comment: @JdeBP May be a missing `"`...

Comment: Don't post in a comment, @havires; edit the question once you have the additional details.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Alright.  I'm going to check out what's been discussed here tonight and then I'll post in the OP about it.  Thanks for the tip.  :)

Comment: Your locale settings are not in order. Read this, then adjust your locale settings to fix the issue: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale

Comment: What's the output of `cat /etc/locale.conf`?